# Color Calibration error on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: colors, color-management, 21.10, monitor-calibration

I just updated to Ubuntu 21.10 and I am facing a problem with my monitor color calibration profiles. I generated ICC profiles for my monitor and could use them with the default "System settings --> Colors" on Ubuntu 21.04. After the upgrade, I still can load the profiles but the colors are completely off (e.g. heavily blue colors and almost no reds). My current work-around is to load the profile through argyllcms --> dispwin, but this is rather inconvenient since I cannot use Nighttime colors and I always need to make sure the profile is applied before editing photos etc.

In addition, I observed a very strange behavior when loading ICC profiles through argyllcms: when I copy/move a file in Nautilus for the first time after reboot, the color profile is unloaded and I have to reload it. But this only happens after the first copy/move action. All concurrent file actions don't cause the problem.

Does someone else have any trouble with ICC profiles on Ubuntu 21.10 and can relate to the problems described? By the way, I have an NVIDIA graphics card installed, running the latest stable drivers (470). Furthermore, when I manually load the profile, I get the following warning: *Dispwin: Warning - new_dispwin: Expected VideoLUT depth 11 doesn't match actual 10*

Any hints and clues are very much appreciated.

Comment: Meanwhile I figured out, that this problem seams to be related to GNOME40. Hopefully, a fix will be available soon...

Comment: I have a two monitor set-up and on the Samsung monitor the colors were off in the way you describe without me messing with color profiles whereas the Dell monitor was fine.  I changed the color profile on the Samsung to SRGB and that seems fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, this is an issue with GNOME 40+. Here is a link to the issue (the first post implies it is an Nvidia driver issue, but later posts confirm that this is not the case, and it affects users of other hardware as well): https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/4071

Fingers crossed it is resolved soon, as it makes GNOME entirely unusable on most distros I have tested.

Comment: So technically speaking, no true solution yet.